# Modifying a list from another form

Tags: c#, .net, forms, listview

I am trying to set up a list in C# and I want it so that when I press the an add button it will open a window with fields where I can enter data press and ok button and then have those text box fields transferred into the list. This is my code for the popup form.

```
public partial class addtoLibraryDialog : Form
{
    public addtoLibraryDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem list = new ListViewItem("name");
        list.SubItems.Add("path");
        listView1.Items.Add(list);
    }
}
```

And I was wondering how I can make it so the listview1 is recognised. I have found information on this outline but as I am new to programming I can't really make heads of tails of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your mainform instance to your secondary form (addtoLibraryDialog) either in its constructor or by an assignment before calling the ShowDialog method.

Simply update in the designer the "Modifiers" property of listview1 : set it to "internal". You will then be able to access to mainform.listview1 in secondary (addtoLibraryDialog) form.

```
public partial class addtoLibraryDialog : Form
{
  internal MainForm mainfom ; // Change "MainForm" by real form name 

  public addtoLibraryDialog()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }


  private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    ListViewItem list = new ListViewItem("name");
    list.SubItems.Add("path");
    mainfom.listView1.Items.Add(list);
  }
 }
```

In MainForm :

```
addtoLibraryDialog dlg=new addtoLibraryDialog() ;
dlg.mainform = this ;
dlg.ShowDialog() ;
```

Comment: "Pass your mainform instance to your secondary form (addtoLibraryDialog) either in its constructor or by an assignment before calling the ShowDialog method." Can you direct me to the code required to do this part as I don't fully understand.

Comment: Thank you so much I managed to get it to work. I did however have to change `private MainForm mainfom ;` to `internal MainForm mainfom ;` for it to work. Hope that won't be an issue.

Comment: Right, it had to be done (no other impact than allowing to compile) . I updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

Add a constructor:

```
public partial class addtoLibraryDialog : Form
{
    ListView objLV;
    public addtoLibraryDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public addtoLibraryDialog(ref ListView lv)
    {
        objLV = lv;
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem list = new ListViewItem("name");
        list.SubItems.Add("path");
        objLV.Items.Add(list);
    }
}
```

To call it from your main form:

```
    ListView myList = new ListView();
    ...
    addtoLibraryDialog dlg=new addtoLibraryDialog(ref myList);
    dlg.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method is to set up a new class file in my program called Global, and put anything that needs multi form access like this into it. So you would simply make a public list in the global file, and access it anywhere in your project

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is sending the ListView as constructor dependency in your form creating a new constructor:

```
public partial addtoLibraryDialog : Form
{
  private readonly ListView _listViewItem;

  public addtoLibraryDialog(ListView listViewItem)
  { 
    InitializeComponent();
    this._listViewItem = listViewItem;
  }

  private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    list = new ListViewItem("name");
    list.SubItems.Add("path");
    this._listViewItem.Items.Add(list);
  }
}

public class MyClass
{
  public void Main()
  {
    addtoLibraryDialog popupForm = new addtoLibraryDialog(this.ListViewItem1);
    addtoLibraryDialog.ShowDialog();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much the same as mine, but you don't pass the ListView object by reference, but by value.  Not 100% sure, but will your code actually update the ListView object when it returns to the Main Form?

Comment: In c# all objects except structures are passed as reference, then it will work fine because the object is the same. You only need ref in structures (sting, int, bool ...)